# Safari won't open after Lion?

Tags: macos, safari

I just finished upgrading to Lion from SL and Safari won't open. When I click it, the app bounces in the dock for a moment then a box pops up and says

**`Safari quit unexpectedly.`**

```
Click Reopen to open the application again. Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple.
```

I tried going to the apple website to download safari but http://www.apple.com/safari/ doesn't contain a download link on the page (to me, at least) and http://www.apple.com/safari/download just redirects to http://www.apple.com/safari/.

I can't find a Safari version for Lion anywhere.

Comment: Is there anything "interesting" in `/var/log/system.log` (or in Console.app)?

Comment: 8/10/12 1:13:58.069 AM ReportCrash: Saved crash report for Safari[26717] version 5.1 (7534.48.3) to /Users/jack/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Safari_2012-08-10-011358_jackss-MacBook.crash

Comment: I'm not sure what is interesting, should I post the full report, its pretty long.

Comment: I found this in the report `Application Specific Information:
objc[26717]: garbage collection is OFF
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: (index >= 0) && (index < [_itemArray count])'`

Comment: From the crash report only the first approx 30 lines are interesting. Did you look at `system.log` as well (search for the time stamp of the crash (01:13 - 01:14 probably))

Comment: Any plugins/extensions installed?

Comment: @patrix, nope. Is there a mirror to Safari 6 somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this pkg to Safari 6:

[http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/37/23/041-5058/lr5tynbldi18zcrqo8a8uq88 rnjushqliu/Safari6Lion.pkg](http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/37/23/041-5058/lr5tynbldi18zcrqo8a8uq88%20rnjushqliu/Safari6Lion.pkg)

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue and error and was able to fix it. To be specific to the previous answer of what to delete:

Open finder and navigate to /System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari

Delete the two WebKit folders located in the Safari folder:

- ./WebKit.framework
- ./WebKit2.framework

Run Software Update and reinstall Safari when prompted.

I have the same problem with Java (before and after the reinstall) so off to fix that now.

Answer (score -1):

You need to delete the  two Webkit folders under system folder.
Then run updates and all will be well

Comment: Can you please add a bit more details? Which specific folders should get deleted, which updates should be run afterwards?

Comment: That's as specific as is possible other than doing it for you myself.

Ring apple, it'll take 5 mins to fix.

Comment: the idea of this site to document answers in a way which allows others to use the answer to resolve similar issues in the future. If I have to do the research again there isn't very much value in the answer in the first place.